# MediaPlayer - creating more than one instance?

Tags: java, android

I have some balls floating on the screen. When they collide I play a sound with MediaPlayer.

```
  public static MediaPlayer create(Resources resources ) {
    try {

        AssetFileDescriptor afd = resources.openRawResourceFd(R.raw.collide);
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        mp.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
        afd.close();
        mp.prepare();
        return mp;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.d("", "create failed:", ex);
        // fall through
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.d("", "create failed:", ex);
        // fall through
    } catch (SecurityException ex) {
        Log.d("", "create failed:", ex);
        // fall through
    }
    return null;
}




  private  void moveBalls(){ //
    for (int i = 0; i < balls.size(); i++) {
        Ball ball1 = balls.get(i);
        for (int a = i + 1; a < balls.size(); a++) {
            Ball ball2 = balls.get(a);
            if(ball1.isColliding(ball2)){
               ball1.Collide(ball1,ball2);
                catchMP = create(resources);
                catchMP.start();
            }
        }
    }
    for(Ball ball : balls){
        ball.step();
    }
}
```

I've already tried methods .stop, .release, checking if it's null - everything.

So. When there are two-four balls everything is fine, it plays normally. When there comes 6-100 balls it stops playing and after a time it starts again (with these sounds that were gone). They are freezing somehow.

Is there any option to solve that?

Answer (score 1):

Okay so once again I need to think more before posting. Moved catchMP = create(resources) to constructor. Don't know, why I declared it here. Works perfectly :)

Thanks!